# Have a variable with multiple types in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, types

I would like to have a variable, which can have multiple types (only ones, I defined), like:

```
var example: String, Int = 0
example = "hi"
```

This variable should be able to hold only values of type Int and String.

Is this possible?

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: no, it is not possible

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Here is how you can achieve it. Works exactly how you'd expect.

```
protocol StringOrInt { }

extension Int: StringOrInt { }
extension String: StringOrInt { }

var a: StringOrInt = "10"
a = 10 //> 10
a = "q" //> "q"
a = 0.8 //> Error
```

**NB!** I would not suggest you to use it in production code. It might be confusing for your teammates.

**UPD:** as @Martin R mentioned: Note that this restricts the possible types only “by convention.” Any module (or source file) can add a `extension MyType: StringOrInt { }` conformance.

Comment: Note that this restricts the possible types only “by convention.” Any module (or source file) can add a `extension MyType: StringOrInt { }` conformance.

Comment: Good remark. Thanks! If you don't mind, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Also worth noting that this only works if the A or B types are classes or structs. You can't declare conformance to another protocol when extending a protocol. Concretely, this means you couldn't make a type like `ArrayOrOptional` because `Optional` is a protocol.

Comment: is it possible for array or dictionary.. I have tried but not working

Comment: Can we confirm StringOrInt to Codable ?

Answer (score 31):

An “enumeration with associated value” might be what you are looking for:

```
enum StringOrInt {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)
}
```

You can either assign a string or an integer:

```
var value: StringOrInt
value = .string("Hello")
// ...
value = .int(123)
```

Retrieving the contents is done with a switch-statement:

```
switch value {
case .string(let s): print("String:", s)
case .int(let n): print("Int:", n)
}
```

If you declare conformance to the `Equatable` protocol then 
you can also check values for equality:

```
enum StringOrInt: Equatable {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)
}

let v = StringOrInt.string("Hi")
let w = StringOrInt.int(0)
if v == w { ... }
```

Comment: In a generic way: `enum Transformer<T: Equatable, U: Equatable> { case first(T); case second(U) }`

Comment: @Carpsen90: Here (as I understand it) OP asked for values holding two *concrete* given types (String or Int). But yes, of course, there are also use cases for generic enums, such as the famous `Result` type (holding a success value or an error).

Comment: getting error Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'StringOrInt' operands

Comment: @VishalChaudhari: That code compiles with Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10.1) and with Swift 5 (Xcode 10.2), I have double-checked it. – Which Xcode version are you using? Did you add the “Equatable” conformance in `enum StringOrInt: Equatable` ?

Answer (score 8):

No, this is not possible for classes, structs, etc.

But it is possible for protocols.

You can this:

```
protocol Walker {
func go()
}
protocol Sleeper {
func sleep()
}

var ab = Walker & Sleeper
```

or even

```
    struct Person {
    var name: String
    }


var ab = Person & Walker & Sleeper
```

But I don't recomment use this way.

More useful this:

```
struct Person: Walker, Sleeper {
/// code
}
var ab = Person
```

Comment: What is included in "*etc*" ?

Comment: @Carpsen90 class struct,  enum , closure(function) , tuple

Comment: This won't achieve what OP is asking for - the `&` operator on protocols creates a new protocol with the requirements of *both* protocols rather than expressing that the resulting type might satisfy the requirements of only *one* of the protocols (but always at least one).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Tuple`.

Example:

```
let example: (String, Int) = ("hi", 0)
```

And access each data by index:

```
let stringFromExampleTuple = example.0 // "hi"
let intFromtExampleTuple = example.1 // 0
```