# How [best] to compare values in a multiple type [but nevertheless controlled] array?

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

Context: an array of values which can be either `[Int]`'s or `[String]`'s - but importantly nothing else - and are also optional, need comparing with potential new values to check for prior existence. Here is the current solution:

```
protocol ValueType {}

extension Int: ValueType {}
extension String: ValueType {}

let values: [[ValueType]?] = []

// ...

values.append(["a", "b", "c"])
values.append([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

This works fine until one gets values from the array to compare, thus:

```
func compare(_ newValues: [ValueType]?, at index: Int) {
    let existingValues = values[i]
    let areTheSame = existingValues == newValues
}
```

At which point, of course:

```
Protocol type 'ValueType' cannot conform to 'Equatable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols
```

How would you resolve this?

Comment: A possible alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53004805/1187415

Comment: thanks @MartinR that looks useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would resolve it by not using a protocol. Make ValueType a union, i.e. an enum with two cases with associated values. In modern Swift, unions are equatable, arrays of arrays are equatable, the problem is solved.