# Function with different parameters

Tags: swift

I have a function where 2 parameters can either be `[Int]?` or `Int`. Do I really have to define 4 functions to solve that problem?

```
func add(x : Float, y : Float, z : Float, out : [Int]? = nil, incoming : [Int]? = nil) -> Bool {
func add(x : Float, y : Float, z : Float, out : Int,          incoming : [Int]? = nil) -> Bool {
func add(x : Float, y : Float, z : Float, out : [Int]? = nil, incoming : Int)          -> Bool {
func add(x : Float, y : Float, z : Float, out : Int,          incoming : Int)          -> Bool {
```

**//Update**

I found [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004623/have-a-variable-with-multiple-types-in-swift) where a variable can have more than one type. But it seems it doesn't work on Arrays (or at least I don't know how to change the code).

Comment: That's a pretty strange API design. What are these parameters used for?

Comment: @Alexander These two parameters are possible connections to other points. They can be connected to 0, 1 or more other points. Mostly they are connected to one other point, so it is inconvenient to put this single value into `[]`.

Comment: The more arguments you have like this, the worse the lack of splatting becomes. https://forums.swift.org/t/explicit-array-splat-for-variadic-functions/11326

Comment: You talk about points, but there aren’t actually any points here, just random  bunches of ints. Are these points of a graph or a mesh or something like that? It looks like you’re missing some domain models here, which could really clean this up.

Comment: @Alexander The data is from an XML file. I want to add more points, connect some of them and write the data back the XML file.

Comment: I would use only `[Int]?` and then check for nil and the count of the array inside the function instead. `func add(x : Float, y : Float, z : Float, out : [Int]?, incoming : [Int]?) -> Bool`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson But it is very inconvenient to use `[]`, because in less than 2 % of cases there are more than 1 values passed to the function. On a German keyboard it is hard to type `[` or `]`.

Comment: @ChristophSchreiber that doesn't exactly answer my question/concern.

Comment: @Alexander I needn't do anything with these points. Only add new points and connect them to 0, 1 or more other points. That's it. No calculations or what ever. Read the XML, add points, write the XML.

Comment: @ChristophSchreiber `I needn't do anything with these points` clearly that's not the case. In the next sentence you write: **1)** `...add new points...` ("adding" points is a kind of "doing something with them", and beside add to *what*? there's a missing domain concept there.) **2)** `...connect them to 0, 1 or more other points...` ("connecting" is another kind of "doing something with them").

Comment: @Alexander Yes, the question is not about what I am doing with the points. The question is how to solve the problem with the different kinds of parameters. Joakim Danelson solved it perfectly

Comment: @ChristophSchreiber You're missing my point (pun intended). Your API would look completely different, and probably entirely circumvent this problem you're running into, if you had `Point`, `Mesh` (or `Grid`, or whatever, I still don't know) entities as real types in your code. Let's get one thing straight: ***there are no points here***. Just bunches of int params.

Comment: @Alexander I read data from an XML file. 3 of the items are x, y and z coordinates of points. My program will add more points and - in most cases - connect them to at least one other point. Then I write back the data to the XML file. In the **question** I never mentioned anything about a "point", so I don't understand why we always have to talk about it. Joakim Danielson understood the problem well and provided the solution I was searching for.

Comment: You don't get it. If you can't come to believe me that you're probably missing huge, I can't really help you.

Comment: You're both solving the wrong problem, which can be entirely circumvented in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution based on the one linked to in the question

```
protocol OneOrManyInt { }

extension Int: OneOrManyInt { }
extension Array: OneOrManyInt where Element == Int {}


func add(x : Float, y : Float, z : Float, out : OneOrManyInt? = nil, incoming : OneOrManyInt? = nil) -> Bool {...}
```

and then it can be used like this for instance

```
add(x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0, out: [1,2,3], incoming: 10)
add(x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0, incoming: 10)
add(x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0, out: [1,2,3])
```

Comment: You are great. I always tried something like `extension Array where ...`

Comment: You can apply this same solution by defining the extension on `Sequence` or `RandomAccessCollection` instead of on `Array` to get more flexibility.  Then, for example, someone could pass in an `ArraySlice` (such as `someArray[i..<j]`) or `someArray.reversed()` as the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can always wrap a single value in an array and pass that to the version taking an array as its input argument.

If you want to expose all 4 versions on the interface level, but don't want to duplicate the implementations, you can simply call the array versions from inside the versions taking a single element.

```
func add(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float, out: [Int]? = nil, incoming: [Int]? = nil) -> Bool {
    ...
}

func add(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float, out: Int, incoming: [Int]? = nil) -> Bool {
    add(x: x, y: y, z: z, out: [out], incoming: incoming)
}

func add(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float, out: [Int]? = nil, incoming: Int) -> Bool {
    add(x: x, y: y, z: z, out: out, incoming: [incoming])
}

func add(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float, out: Int, incoming: Int) -> Bool {
    add(x: x, y: y, z: z, out: [out], incoming: [incoming])
}
```

Comment: Of course I will not write redundant code and will do it as you mentioned it. The question is: Must I define 4 functions?

Comment: @ChristophSchreiber considering that 3 out of the 4 functions call the same 4th implementation, you could define only that 1 actually, it really depends on what is the interface you want to achieve.