# How would I reformat the system image code in my array for custom images or media?

Tags: swift, macos, listview, navigationview

How would I reformat the code to handle custom images and not system images in my array, so i may replace the titles for custom png logos or path, mp4, etc... but for now just custom images?

[image: Cotharticren Menu Array]

I want to use my own icons down the road for online database access and menus sharing other menu functions like palettes in photoshop create your atom on this menu go to another menu, apply thermal dynamics, go to another menu apply simulations etc...

```
struct Option: Hashable, Identifiable {
    // Identifier for Option !! MUST be unique
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let imageName: String
}
struct SubOption: Hashable, Identifiable {
    // Identifier for Option !! MUST be unique
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let imageName: String
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentOption: Int = 0
    @State var currentSubOption: Int = 0
    
    
    let options: [Option] = [
        .init(id: 1, title: "DART Meadow", imageName: "sun.max.fill"),
        .init(id: 2, title: "Research", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 3, title: "Navigation", imageName: "moon.stars.fill"),
        .init(id: 4, title: "Shelf", imageName: "archivebox"),
        .init(id: 5, title: "Chest", imageName: "shippingbox"),
        .init(id: 6, title: "Crate", imageName: "bonjour"),
        .init(id: 7, title: "Manufacturing", imageName: "gear"),
        .init(id: 8, title: "Warehouse", imageName: "archivebox.fill"),
        .init(id: 9, title: "Journal", imageName: "note.text"),
    ]
    let suboptions: [SubOption] = [
        .init(id: 10, title: "Sigcothian", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 11, title: "DART Edge", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 12, title: "Orbit", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 13, title: "Mass", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 14, title: "Volume", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 15, title: "Weight", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 16, title: "Density", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 17, title: "ATM 26", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 18, title: "Break", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 19, title: "Gas", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 20, title: "Liquid", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 21, title: "Solid", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 22, title: "Crystalline", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 23, title: "Nozzle", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 24, title: "Decibel", imageName: "flame"),
        
    ]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                
                NavigationView{
                    ListView(options: options, currentSelection: $currentOption)
                    
                    switch (currentOption) {
                        
                    case 1:
                        
                        MainView()
                        
                    case 2:
                        NavigationView{
                            ResearchSubView(suboptions: suboptions, currentSubSelection: $currentSubOption)
                            
                            switch (currentSubOption) {
                                
                            case 10:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    Text("Sigcothian")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .bold()
                                        .colorInvert()
                                        .padding(.top, 60)
                                    Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                                }
                            case 11:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    Text("DART Edge")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .bold()
                                        .colorInvert()
                                        .padding(.top, 60)
                                    Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                                }
                            case 12:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    OrbitNodeView()
                                }
                            case 13:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    Text("Mass")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .bold()
                                        .colorInvert()
                                        .padding(.top, 60)
                                    Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                                }
                            case 14:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    Text("Volume")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .bold()
                                        .colorInvert()
                                        .padding(.top, 60)
                                    Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                                }
                            case 15:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    Text("Weight")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .bold()
                                        .colorInvert()
                                        .padding(.top, 60)
                                    Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                                }
                            case 16:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    Text("Density")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .bold()
                                        .colorInvert()
                                        .padding(.top, 60)
                                    Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                                }
                            case 17:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    ATM26NodeView()
                                }
                            case 18:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    Text("Break")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .bold()
                                        .colorInvert()
                                        .padding(.top, 60)
                                    Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                                }
                            case 19:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    Text("Gas")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .bold()
                                        .colorInvert()
                                        .padding(.top, 60)
                                    Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                                }
                            case 20:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    Text("Liquid")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .bold()
                                        .colorInvert()
                                        .padding(.top, 60)
                                    Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                                }
                            case 21:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    Text("Solid")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .bold()
                                        .colorInvert()
                                        .padding(.top, 60)
                                    Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                                }
                            case 22:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    Text("Crystalline")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .bold()
                                        .colorInvert()
                                        .padding(.top, 60)
                                    Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                                }
                            case 23:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    NozzleNodeView()
                                        .padding(.leading, 15)
                                        .padding(.trailing, 15)
                                    Content2View()
                                        .padding(.top, 60)
                                    
                                }
                            case 24:
                                ScrollView( .vertical) {
                                    Text("Decibel")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .bold()
                                        .colorInvert()
                                        .padding(.top, 60)
                                    Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                                }
                            default:
                                
                                MainView()
                            }
                            
                        }
                    case 3:
                        ScrollView( .vertical) {
                            Text("Navigation")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .bold()
                                .colorInvert()
                                .padding(.top, 60)
                            Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                        }
                    case 4:
                        ScrollView( .vertical) {
                            Text("Shelf")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .bold()
                                .colorInvert()
                                .padding(.top, 60)
                            Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                        }
                    case 5:
                        ScrollView( .vertical) {
                            Text("Chest")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .bold()
                                .colorInvert()
                                .padding(.top, 60)
                            Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                        }
                    case 6:
                        ScrollView( .vertical) {
                            Text("Crate")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .bold()
                                .colorInvert()
                                .padding(.top, 60)
                            Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                        }
                    case 7:
                        ScrollView( .vertical) {
                            Text("Manufacturing")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .bold()
                                .colorInvert()
                                .padding(.top, 60)
                            Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                        }
                    case 8:
                        ScrollView( .vertical) {
                            Text("Warehouse")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .bold()
                                .colorInvert()
                                .padding(.top, 60)
                            Image("Cotharticrenmindnode600")
                        }
                    case 9:
                        JournalView()
                    default:
                        
                        MainView()
                    }
                    
                }.background(Color.white)
                
            }
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}




struct MainView: View {
    
    var body: some View{
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                
                
                Image("CotharticrenArcLakeMainMenu900")
                    .shadow(radius: 6)
                
            }
        }.frame(width: 900, height: 670, alignment: .center).padding(.top, 60)
            .background(Color.white)
        
        Spacer()
        
        
    }
    
}

struct ListView: View {
    let options: [Option]
    @Binding var currentSelection: Int
    
    var body: some View{
        ScrollView( .vertical) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack(alignment: .top) {
                        HStack(alignment: .top) {
                            VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                                Circle()
                                    .stroke(Color.init(red: 0.9, green: 0.95, blue: 0.2, opacity: 1), lineWidth: 2)
                                    .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.myAlignment)
                                { d in d[.leading] }
                                .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.myAlignment)
                                { d in d[.bottom] }
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                
                                Circle()
                                    .stroke(Color.init(red: 0.25, green: 0.9, blue: 0.2, opacity: 1), lineWidth: 2)
                                    .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.myAlignment)
                                { d in d[.leading] }
                                .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.myAlignment)
                                { d in d[.bottom] }
                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Circle()
                                        .stroke(Color.init(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 1, opacity: 1), lineWidth: 2)
                                        .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.myAlignment)
                                    { d in d[.leading] }
                                    .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.myAlignment)
                                    { d in d[.bottom] }
                                    .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        HStack(alignment: .top) {
                            Image("dm120")
                            
                                .shadow(radius: 3)
                                .padding(.top, 10)
                        }
                        
                        
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                        
                        
                        .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    }.padding(.top, 20).padding(.leading, 10)
                    Divider().padding(5)
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        VStack(alignment: .center) {
                            
                            Image("Cotharticrenmindnode150").padding(20)
                            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                                Text("You've never plotted an Edge?")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.shadow(radius: 3)
                Divider().padding(12)
                //Menu
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(options, id: \.self) {option in
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: option.imageName)
                                .frame(width: 20)
                            
                            Text(option.title)
                            // Don't even have to use current = options[currentSelection] anymore:
                                .foregroundColor(currentSelection == option.id ? .accentColor : .primary)
                        }
                        .padding(8)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            // Set the currentSelection to the ID of the option
                            currentSelection = option.id
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }.frame(width: 235, height: 670, alignment: .leading).padding(5)
        
        
        
        
    }
}







struct ResearchSubView: View {
    let suboptions: [SubOption]
    @Binding var currentSubSelection: Int
    
    var body: some View{
        ScrollView( .vertical) {
            
            //Menu
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(suboptions, id: \.self) {suboption in
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: suboption.imageName)
                            .frame(width: 20)
                            .colorInvert()
                        
                        Text(suboption.title)
                            .colorInvert()
                        // Don't even have to use current = options[currentSelection] anymore:
                            .foregroundColor(currentSubSelection == suboption.id ? .accentColor : .primary)
                    }
                    .padding(8)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        // Set the currentSelection to the ID of the option
                        currentSubSelection = suboption.id
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
        }.frame(width: 120, height: 670, alignment: .leading).padding(5)
        
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got by with 2 optional variables, but looking back, that seems kind of weird. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53004805/14351818

Answer (score 1):

After correspondence with online individuals. I’ve Found a solution to be an elementary ListView that is populated by an array id with an onGesture function.