# Swift: How can different types be used for a variable in a struct?

Tags: swift, generics

I have this TypeScript expression:

```js
type ApexAxisChartSeries = {
  data:
    | (number | null)[]
    | {
        x: any;
        y: any;
      }[]
}[]
```

I would convert it to Swift. How can `data` be expressed, that it can be either be array of objects, or array of numbers?

I get to here:

```swift
struct ApexData {
    var x: Float
    var y: Float
}

struct ApexAxisChartSeries {
    var data: [ApexData]
}
```

Do I need an enum inside struct?

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Have a variable with multiple types in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53004623/1187415)

Comment: @János x and y should be floating type or null, correct?