# Can we return multiple values based on return type

Tags: swift

Is it possible that one function can return multiple values?

```
func dataChange(type: String) -> (String || Int) {
    if (type == "string"){
      return "stackover flow"
    }
    return 123
}
```

Can the **dataChange** function return different values based on an if condition.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Maybe the closest way is an enum with associated values. But this depends on your **real** code.

Comment: Even though this is possible in dynamic languages like Python or JS, it's very often a mistake. Usually you want to return one of several possible types which are related to each other. For example, having a function return `AirplaneSeatingChart || OilRigMonthlyOutput` just wouldn't make sense. Presumably, you want to return one of several types which are related to each other. For example, you might have a function that returns an `NSImageView` or `NSTextView`. Both of these are unified through being different kinds of `NSView``. Superclasses or protocols are the way to model this commonality

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/53004623/1187415

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Swift does not support functions with multiple return types.

But there are a few possible ways to handle this. An enum with associated values is one way.

```
enum DifferentTypes {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)
}

func dataChange(type: String) -> DifferentTypes {
    if type == "string" {
        return .string("stack overflow")
    } else {
        return .int(123)
    }
}

let res = dataChange(type: "whatever")
switch res {
    case .string(let string):
        print(string)
    case .int(let int):
        print(int)
}
```

Another would be a tuple:

```
func dataChange(type: String) -> (String?, Int?) {
    if type == "string" {
        return ("stack overflow", nil)
    } else {
        return (nil, 123)
    }
}

let res = dataChange(type: "whatever")
if let string = res.0 {
    print(string)
} else if let int = res.1 {
    print(int)
}
```

While this works it's not nearly as good as the `enum` version.

And as an alternate to the tuple version you could create a `strut` with two optional properties but that's really no better than the tuple version.