How can I accept one of two types as argument to a function?
I would like to write a function that only accepts Int or Double and returns different values based on them. The actual use-case features a SwiftUI struct: View  with somewhat more complex init(). If possible, I would like to avoid duplicating it with a different input type. How can this be done?
Ideally, I would like a solution that looks like this:
struct MyStruct<T>: View where T is (Int | Double) {  // Specifying type here is the problematic part
var value: T
var description: String

init(_ value: T) {
   self.value = value
   switch value {
      case is Int:
         description = "Integer"
      case is Double:
         description = "Double"
   }
}

var body: some View {
   Text(description)
}


Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53004623/1187415

Only Int or Double? Are you sure you cannot generalise this to a common protocol like SignedNumeric?

https://www.biteinteractive.com/little-swift-tricks-boxing-multiple-types/

There are at least two options:

A custom dummy protocol which Int and Double adopt in an extension
protocol IntOrDouble {}
extension Int : IntOrDouble {}
extension Double : IntOrDouble {}

struct MyStruct<T>: View where T : IntOrDouble {
    var value: T
    let description: String

    init(_ value: T) {
       self.value = value
        description = value is Int ? "Integer" : "Double"
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(description)
    }
}


An enum with associated values
enum IntOrDouble {
    case integer(Int)
    case double(Double)
}

struct MyStruct: View, CustomStringConvertible {
    var value: IntOrDouble

    var body: some View {
        Text(description)
    }

    var description : String {
        switch value {
            case .integer(let intValue):
                return "Integer \(intValue)"
            case .double(let doubleValue):
                return "Double \(doubleValue)"
        }
    }
}




value is Int ? "Integer" : "Double" this is error prone, because you could add a new conformance to IntOrDouble (which is unlikely given the name, but stranger things have happened), which would always incorrectly hit the "double" case.

In general generics are use for supporting diverse types. But as you want to exclusively support only Int and Double I think you can do something like this:
import SwiftUI

protocol MyType {
    var typeDescription: String { get }
}

extension Int: MyType {
    var typeDescription: String {
        return "Integer"
    }
}

extension Double: MyType {
    var typeDescription: String {
        return "Double"
    }
}

struct MyStruct<T: MyType>: View {
    var value: T
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(value.typeDescription)
    }
}

#Preview {
    MyStruct(value: 2) // Integer
    //MyStruct(value: 2.3) // Double
}


